# Can I get the full version of Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, noobs, windows, software-compatibility

Here is what i was thinking. download Windows and NOOBS on an SD card and install it that way. Will that work?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not get Windows 10 to work on the Pi.  Note, I use Windows 10 to mean what you mean when you ask the question.

There is no relationship between the abilities of the similarly named Windows 10 IoT and Windows 10 as you see on an Intel/AMD PC.

Windows 10 IoT is intended to be used, perhaps with a tiny dedicated GUI, on internet connected gadgets.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to raspberrypi.org/downloads there is an image file for the RPi version of Windows 10 (IoT). The full version of Windows 10 hasn't been modified for the Pi and, as such, I don't recommend it.

Comment: There is a download for Windows 10 IoT core, but not the full version.